# Prove that every set that is open with respect to $\|\cdot\|_a$ is also open with respect to $\|\cdot\|_b$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, solution-verification

Is my proof below valid? Thank you.

$\def\n{{\mathbf n}}
\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\w{{\mathbf w}}
\def\r{{\mathbf r}}
\def\y{{\mathbf y}}
\def\a{{\mathbf a}}
\def\b{{\mathbf b}}
\def\p{{\mathbf p}}
\def\X{{\mathcal X}}
\def\Y{{\mathcal Y}}
\def\T{{\mathcal T}}
\def\S{{\mathcal S}}
\def\O{{\mathcal O}}
\def\R{{\mathbb R}}                            
\def\Rhat{{\widehat{\R}}}$

Let $\|\cdot\|_a$ and$\|\cdot\|_b$ represent two norms on $\R^n$ and suppose the norms are equivalent, that is, there exist constants $0<c_1 \le c_2 <\infty$ such that for all $\x\in\R^n$, $c_1\|\x\|_a \le \|\x\|_b \le c_2\|\x\|_a$.
Prove that  every set that is open with respect to $\|\cdot\|_a$ is also open with respect to $\|\cdot\|_b$.  (Note: The set $\O\subseteq\R^n$ is open with respect to $\|\cdot\|_a$ if for every $\x\in\O$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that the set $\{\y\colon\|\x-\y\|_a<\epsilon\}\subseteq\O$.  Similarly, $\O$ is open with respect to $\|\cdot\|_b$ if for every $\x\in\O$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that the set $\{\y\colon\|\x-\y\|_b<\epsilon\}\subseteq\O$.)

$\textbf{Solution:}$ editing

Comment: "...and suppose the norms are equivalent..." as a side remark, any two norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are (Lipshcitz) equivalent.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski yes, correct. I rewrote the problem from the book I am studying.

Comment: Also in the line starting with "Now, we are given..." 1) You should probably use another variable name in: $||x||_b \le c_2 ||x||_a$ in stead of $x$ because $x$ is already specified and fixed, whereas you want to apply the inequality to $u = x-y$. 2) You write "for some $b>0$". I assume you meant $c_2>0$ in stead. Other than these minor remarks, I believe that the proof is fine.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski I see, yes, sorry about this. I fixed it, thank you Marko!

Comment: You're welcome. Also personally, for clarity, I'd write "Now, **by the definition of equivalence we are given, for any $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$,**..." and then "which implies, **by setting $w = x-y$**, ...". Maybe more experienced members can comment on this part.

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski ok, thank you. I just made the edit. I believe it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that after the discussion in the comments, the proof is clear and complete. As a last remark, in the third line of the solution I'd probably prefer "$...||x-y||_b \le c_2||x-y||_a$ **,and/hence** if$...$".